# FPS Videogame, maybe Russian, where you are a soldier in a theocracy, and wear golden armor

Tags: story-identification, video-games

This is bugging me, because I'm pretty sure I had it installed on my old computer. It was an FPS, I think originating from Russia. The setting was sci-fi, with a touch of religious mysticism. The protagonist is a soldier for the government, which is a bit of a theocracy, claiming to be in touch with their god, and empowered by them. I think the very first bit of the game involves a small level where you enter a gate, which is either stated, or implied, to be an exit from the afterlife after dying in righteous battle. I remember there were choices as to what skills were taken, ranging from stealth to gun combat to melee combat, before the first level. That first level, I remember there was some sort of a chase after a criminal, with other goons forcing the protagonist into running firefights during the pursuit. After that level, there were a bit on-base, which seemed fairly extensive, involving walking through something like a city, complete with canals. I don't remember if I saw the protagonist, but his fellow soldiers wear golden armor with a lot of tubes and lumps, kind of elephantine in the head shape. After that, the next level had the protagonist fighting in a slum city, I think pursuing some sort of rebel "General". I remember looking up some info on the game, and learning there were multiple paths, including violence, bribing the "General", or convincing him via debate of the rightness of your actions. I'm pretty sure, when I looked up the game, that they said that you eventually come to realize that the government you serve is corrupt. I know, kind of a standard trope.

I think it might have been built on the *Deus Ex* engine, just based on graphics and the skillset.  It might have started life as a mod, but I think they'd licensed it by the time of release.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've played it, but your description sounds like [E.Y.E.: Divine Cybermancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.Y.E.:_Divine_Cybermancy) There's golden armor, religious overtones, a sprawling base you explore after the first mission, and in the second mission you track down a rogue general in a slum city with canals and either recruit or kill him. There are a lot of customization options so you can build stealth, ranged, melee characters, but no preset classes iirc.

However, it's French rather than Russian, is built in the source engine rather than Deus Ex, and the first level doesn't really match your description. Also you play as a member of a theocratic secret organization embedded within a corrupt secular government, rather than a direct agent of a corrupt theocratic government.

Comment: That does look like a good match. And it is in my Steam library. I'm installing it now to verify.

Comment: Replayed, indeed the one I was thinking of. Thank you.

Comment: Enjoy gaining Brozouf